# Python 3.3: invalid syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm confused as to why I am getting an invalid syntax error in this program. I imagine it is fairly simple, but I'm very new to this. Here's the whole thing:

```
# Welcome Message
print ("Hello and welcome to the Plesha EasyTube Wizard!")
print ("Today we will be gathering measurements from you to determine the \
materials and cost of your tubes.")
print ("All measurements should be in centimeters!")
print ()

# Collect user inputs
height = float(input("Let's begin: What is the height of you desired tube? "))
radius = float(input("And what is the radius? "))
count = int(input("How many would you like? "))

# Set Constants
steelPrice = 0.14
rubberPrice = 0.02

# Calculations
import math
singleTubeVol = math.pi * (radius ** 2) * height
allTubeVol = singleTubeVol * count
singleTubeSurface = (2 * math.pi * (radius ** 2)) + (2 * math.pi * radius * height)
allTubeSurface = singleTubeSurface * count
singleTubeRubber = 2 * math.pi * (radius + 0.5) * height
allTubeRubber = singleTubeRubber * count
steelCost = steelPrice * allTubeSurface
rubberCost = rubberPrice * allTubeRubber
totalCost = rubberCost + steelCost

# Output
                                                      V------ here is where the problem is
print ("You wanted ", count " tubes in the dimesions ", height \
   " centimeters by ", radius " centimeters (radius).")
print ("The volume of a single tube of your specifications is: ", singleTubeVol)
print ("The total volume of your tube order will be ", allTubeVol)
print ("You will require ", allTubeSurface " square centimeters of steel. Totalling "\
   , steelCost "in price." )
print ("You will require ", allTubeRubber " square centimeters of rubber. Totalling "\
   , rubberCost " in price." )
print ("Your total cost for this order will be ", totalCost)
```

I appreciate any help for a newb.

Comment: Where does it say the syntax error is?  Please narrow it down to the line it says is causing the problem.

Comment: @ColeJohnson `print()` just creates a blank line. It would be equivalent to saying `print("")`. He probably wanted to just open op a space in the output of the program.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot a few commas:

```
print ("You wanted ", count, " tubes in the dimesions ", height,
#                     -----^                              -----^
```

and more again on the next lines:

```
   " centimeters by ", radius, " centimeters (radius).")
#                       -----^
print ("The volume of a single tube of your specifications is: ", singleTubeVol)
print ("The total volume of your tube order will be ", allTubeVol)
print ("You will require ", allTubeSurface, " square centimeters of steel. Totalling "
#                                    -----^
   , steelCost, "in price." )
#        -----^
print ("You will require ", allTubeRubber, " square centimeters of rubber. Totalling "
#                                   -----^
   , rubberCost, " in price." )
#         -----^
```

I'd be better if you used formatting:

```
print("""\
You wanted {count} tubes in the dimesions {height:0.2f} centimeters by {radius:0.2f} centimeters (radius).
The volume of a single tube of your specifications is: {singleTubeVol:0.2f}
The total volume of your tube order will be {allTubeVol:0.2f}
You will require {allTubeSurface:0.2f} square centimeters of steel. Totalling {steelCost:0.2f} in price.
You will require {allTubeRubber:0.2f} square centimeters of rubber. Totalling {rubberCost:0.2f} in price.
Your total cost for this order will be {totalCost:0.2f}""".format(**locals()))
```

This uses the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), combined with `"""` a triple-qouted string to format the text in one go, formatting the float values with two decimals after the decimal point.

Sample output:

```
Hello and welcome to the Plesha EasyTube Wizard!
Today we will be gathering measurements from you to determine the materials and cost of your tubes.
All measurements should be in centimeters!

Let's begin: What is the height of you desired tube? 10
And what is the radius? 2.5
How many would you like? 3
You wanted 3 tubes in the dimesions 10.00 centimeters by 2.50 centimeters (radius).
The volume of a single tube of your specifications is: 196.35
The total volume of your tube order will be 589.05
You will require 589.05 square centimeters of steel. Totalling 82.47 in price.
You will require 565.49 square centimeters of rubber. Totalling 11.31 in price.
Your total cost for this order will be 93.78
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. Needed a LOT of commas, actually. I was confused because of where it pointed me.

Answer (score 0):

The quoting you're using can be tricky, so you should better try to format the parameters for print, something like this sould improve a little bit:

```
 # Output ------ here is where the problem is
print ("You wanted %d tubes in the dimesions %d centimeters by %d centimeters (%d)." %(count, height, radius, radius))
print ("The volume of a single tube of your specifications is: ", singleTubeVol)
print ("The total volume of your tube order will be ", allTubeVol)
print ("You will require %d square centimeters of steel. Totalling %d in price." %(allTubeSurface, steelCost))
print ("You will require %d square centimeters of rubber. Totalling %d in price." %(allTubeRubber, rubberCost) )
print ("Your total cost for this order will be ", totalCost)
```

still i'm sure that there is a much better solution.

Comment: This was how I had it originally. I'm going through school and apparently for the class I'm taking this format is discouraged. Funny thing is it all printed correctly in this format so I wish I could use it.