# PCI_st library for TMS/EEG dataset does not work with me, any solution?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me why this line of code

from pci_st import *

Gives me the following error in python?

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pci_st'

This is based on this source https://github.com/renzocom/PCIst, used for TMS/EEG dataset to detect consciousness.

Thank you so much for your help, I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the github page example, they use ** to import. To fix your error:

```
from pci_st import **
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I want to add ** it gives me this syntax error:   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: from pci_st import **
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You must have made a typo somewhere in your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957298/python-3-3-invalid-syntax-error

Comment: I only wrote that line

Comment: With one * , it gives me:   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pci_st'

Comment: With two ** , it gives me SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you install this library with pip in the first place?

Comment: pip install pci_st ? It says:                                                                                           ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pci_st (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pci_st

Comment: Try to install it with python3 syntax: python3 -m pip install pci_st

Comment: It did not work. The same error as above.

Comment: In this case I think the issue is that you do not have the latest Python version installed. Can you upgrade your Python, and then try to install the package with pip again?

Comment: This is my python version: Python 3.9.7